# Is there any way to extract the payload from a UDP packet in real time and use that payload for another application?

Tags: python, networking, wireshark

Im receiving some udp packets from a network interface called tun0. I am able to see those packets through wireshark. What I need is to extract the payloads from those packets. I tried to use python sockets but Im unable to extract the payload and I think thats because of the packets have a uip stack. Is there anyway to take the payload from the wireshark directly to real time processes? Or is there any other suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like using wireshark is only a workaround since you could not get using Python UDP sockets to work.  What was the problem using Python UDP sockets (since this sounds like a much better approach).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to accomplish is to get the udp.stream out of Wireshark without the headers.
If youre using Windows you might wanna use powershell:
http://winpowershell.blogspot.com/2010/01/powershell-udp-clientserver.html?m=1

But if you're using linux or don't have powershell/ not comfortable using it you may use tshark like this.
tshark -r $file -R '(ip.addr eq 10.0.0.X and ip.addr eq 10.0.0.X) and (udp.port eq X and udp.port eq X)' -T fields -e data

Hopefully this will works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually the udp packets are coming through a com port (I connect the cable to the /dev/ttyACM0). And I make an interface called tun0 and tun0 interface has a 127.x.x.x kind of local address. I use wireshark to observe packets coming from that interface. However how can I identify the correct udp port in this case?

Comment: If you have the Wireshark pcap you can look up at endpoints and find the correct udp port manually, https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChStatConversations.html.    As well you may just record only by IP address instead of upd.port